# Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' - Debian 10

Tags: mysql, php, debian, apache2

I'm setting up a webserver, using Debian 10, Apache2, PHP7.3, MariaDB and PHPMyAdmin.

When i start Apache2 it wil say:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/etc/php/7.3/mods-available/mysqli.ini' (tried: /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/mysqli.ini (/etc/php/7.3/mods-available/mysqli.ini: invalid ELF header), /usr/lib/php/20180731//etc/php/7.3/mods-available/mysqli.ini.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731//etc/php/7.3/mods-available/mysqli.ini.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_allocator)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Apache2 will start fine, but i want to use it, so i will need to fix it. Tried enabling it in php.ini and when i disable it, the error will stay. I did restart Apache2 after each adjustment.

Edit: Reinstalled MySQL & MySQLi worked kind off. New error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/etc/php/7.3/mods-available/mysqli.ini' (tried: /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/mysqli.ini (/etc/php/7.3/mods-available/mysqli.ini: invalid ELF header), /usr/lib/php/20180731//etc/php/7.3/mods-available/mysqli.ini.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731//etc/php/7.3/mods-available/mysqli.ini.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_allocator)) in Unknown on line 0
```

The mysqli.so is in the right place, but it goes wrong in the file. The file is compiled code, so changing things is not really an option. Has anyone a good fix for this problem or is it a new install?

Comment: I solved the problem by reinstalling PHP, with all library's! Restarted apache and solved. Let this question open if someone finds a answer.

Comment: How exactly did you "reinstall with all libraries"?

Comment: @JosFaber Try: sudo apt update && sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php && sudo systemctl restart apache2   || .  That worked for me.